# PrimeNG components and documentation versions incompatible?

Tags: primeng

We have a project based in primeng 9.1.3, and when I attempt to look at the documentation, there seems to be a discrepancy, or maybe I'm just overlooking something.  We started this project a few years ago and it seems like there isn't an easy path to upgrading to 10.0 and beyond, so that's why we're staying with 9.x.

On the primeng releases (https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng) the latest 9.x I see is 9.1.3. But when I go to the docs (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v9-lts/#/), I see 9.2.8-lts.

I looked into some of the source code and some things that are in the docs properties are not in the release... The main issue is the 508 compliance functionality discrepancies in the docs vs release.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something, and hoping those that are more familiar with primeng can point me in the right direction.

I can't figure out why the docs version and the release version don't match up.  I can't find the docs for 9.1.3 and I can't find the release for 9.2.8, and its painful to try and dig through the source code each time I want something to pass 508 compliance.

Comment: Please don't use incorrect tags. You are not using PrimeFaces (Java Server Faces).

Comment: Please do not edit the tags I provide. It is your opinion that it isn't correct and I disagree.  The documentation is hosted on primefaces (as  you can clearly see in the URL), and I'm attempting to get this possibly to whomever owns the documentation/release connection, thank you.

Comment: Please read the description of [tag:primefaces]. It clearly is not the technology you are using. What hostname your documentation is hosted on is irrelevant.

Comment: I disagree, and its not my documentation.  Its where all of primeng documentation is hosted.  thank you.

Comment: Also, please read the description of [tag:primeng]

Comment: I'm sorry but @JasperdeVries is right - the primefaces tag should be removed. The tag is associated with the PrimeFaces component library created by the same company that created the PrimeNG library. I don't know why the PrimeNG library's documentation is hosted under the primefaces domain name but except for originating at the same company, there is no connection to PrimeFaces or the primefaces tag.

Answer (score 1):

The latest 9.x version is actually 9.2.8, as can be seen under the [primeng-lts npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng-lts/v/9.2.8).

The reason why the latest version that appears on https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng is 9.1.3 is that 9.1.3 is the last version of 9.x that isn't an LTS version and is an STS version, under the MIT license. The LTS versions are commercial versions.

You can read about the PrimeNG version lifecycle [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/lts). You can also see in the diagram there that version 9.1.4 is marked as the first 9.x version to receive LTS status.

Comment: thank you for clarifying.  Do you know where I can find the documentation for 9.1.3?

Comment: I don't think it exists. Maybe there are copies of it in their internal version control tool but it most likely not accessible to the general public. I'd try contacting them with that question, but I assume that's what they'll tell you.

Comment: You might find a past version of the documentation on one of those web archiving sites that store copies of sites in different points in time.